# Javascript object has data, but isn't populating textboxes it in MVC view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a method from my controller passing data as json, and when I step through the javascript, I am seeing that the data made it to the JavaScript object, but for some reason its not populating my textboxes. When I am debugging in Chrome, I see the data in the object and no errors are being thrown.

At first I tried doing this...

```
    public ActionResult Preferences()
    {
        GetClientResult();
        return View();
    }
```

But I thought may have been the problem, so I changed things around and now it looks like this

In my controller I have..

```
public JsonResult GetClientResult()
    {
        OQOE = new OQOEDAL();

        List<ClientInformation> ClientList = OQOE.GetClientInformation();

        return Json(ClientList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and my javascript file looks like this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    GetClientInformation();
});

    function GetClientInformation() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: AddClientURLParam.AddGetClientInformationURL,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            return DataToGet(data);
        }
    })
}

    function DataToGet(clientInfoData) {
    $("#txtCompanyName").val(clientInfoData[0].customerName);
    $("#txtAddress1").val(clientInfoData[0].address1);
    $("#txtAddress2").val(clientInfoData[0].address2);
    $("#txtCity").val(clientInfoData[0].city);
    $("#txtState").val(clientInfoData[0].state);
    $("#txtZip").val(clientInfoData[0].zip);
    $("#txtEmail").val(clientInfoData[0].email);
    $("#txtContact").val(clientInfoData[0].contactName);
    $("#txtPhone").val(clientInfoData[0].phone);
    $("#txtWorkPhone").val(clientInfoData[0].work);
    $("#txtMobile").val(clientInfoData[0].mobile);
    $("#txtFax").val(clientInfoData[0].fax);
    $("#txtOther").val(clientInfoData[0].other);
}
```

and my View has this...

```
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="YourInfo">
    <h4>Please fill out your Information below.</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="txtCompanyName" class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Company Name:</b></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input id="txtCompanyName" type="text" class="form-control max-size" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><h4><b>Address</b></h4></legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtAddress1" class="control-label col-md-2">Address</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="txtAddress1" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtAddress2" class="control-label col-md-2">Address2</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="txtAddress2" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtCity" class="control-label col-md-2">City</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="txtCity" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtState" class="control-label col-md-2">State</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="txtState" type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <label for="txtZip" class="control-label col-md-2">Zip/Postal</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="txtZip" type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtEmail" class="control-label col-md-2">Email</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="txtEmail" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <fieldset>
            <legend><h4><b>Contact</b></h4></legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtContact" class="control-label col-md-2">Contact</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="txtContact" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtPhone" class="control-label col-md-2">Phone</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="txtPhone" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtWorkPhone" class="control-label col-md-2">Work</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="txtWorkPhone" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtFax" class="control-label col-md-2">Fax</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="txtFax" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtMobile" class="control-label col-md-2">Mobile</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="txtMobile" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtOther" class="control-label col-md-2">Other</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input id="txtOther" type="text" class="form-control max-size" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-10">
            <input id="btnSaveClientInfo" type="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <input id="btnCancelClientInfo" type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the content of data?

Comment: Your controller method is returning a collection of items (`List<ClientInformation>`) but you only seem to want one item. Your should consider using `var client = OQOE.GetClientInformation().FirstOrDefault()` so you don't post unnecessary data to the client.

Comment: And what really is the point of this (as opposed to passing your model to the view and generating your view correctly using strongly typed html helpers?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I am relatively new to MVC, only been working with it for awhile

Comment: I don't understand what should expected with `return DataToGet(data);`

Comment: @AndrewOrlov, its returning the data thats being called to a javascript object and that object is supposed to be populating all the textboxes with the data that it holds

Comment: Really? Your function `DataToGet` doesn't return anything. It is just populating values for inputs.

Comment: @Chris, You need to go to the MVC site and work through some tutorials, in particular how to create a view and bind your model to it.

Comment: @AndrewOrlov,ok, this is how i am seeing things...I call the GetClientInformation(), that returns the data from my method GetClientResult() and puts the returned data into the function DataToGet(clientInfo) and that function is supposed to be populating the inputs with the returned data. When I am debugging, I see the values in the DataToGet, but the inputs don't get the values.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i agree with you a 100% I know from what I have seen in tutorials that I am not doing things the "right" way as in the tutorials

Comment: @Chris, just because you're trying to return something from your AJAX `success` handler. Remove your `return` keyword at first.

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems that problem will be solved with removing keyword `return` from AJAX `success` handler. Function `DataToGet` doesn't return anything meaningful in this case. It is just populating inputs values. So. My answer is based on comments debates.

Comment: Once I remove the return from the success handler, i start getting errors, one such error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Comment: @Chris This is an another question that's don't related with your initial one. We don't know anything about your model, serialization and other things. If you had some data in `DataToGet` parameter before - you will get it and for now. Just debug. And ask another question.

Comment: I am debugging and my question will be the same, why won't the data in DataToGet populate the input fields. My apologies if I am sounding aggravated, its not intended

Comment: We can not give an answer why are you getting TypeError with your initial question. It is related with your model serialization issues for now. And it is another question.

Comment: @Chris 1) As you can see - you've got no any properties "address" (I hope that you'd copy/paste your console error) in you initial question. 2) you're trying to read this "address" property from undefined object. It will be much better if you will show us your model.